# How do I get a full article with description and image using Yahoo pipes?

Tags: regex, rss, yahoo-pipes

http://bit.ly/4z5IFj

This rss feed doesn't contain the post image, maybe because the site arranges the image improperly.  The image comes over the title, and the image do not have full either (like in css)

example post: http://bit.ly/LEj3tj

```
<div id="newsItemComplete">
<p><img src="news_images/712315777drugs1.jpg" alt="Over 19,000 suspects ...." /></p>

<h2 class="completeNewsTitle" style="margin-top:10px;">Over 19,000 suspects ....</h2>   

<p class="newsDateStamp"  style="width:100%; float:left; margin:0;">June 14, 2012&nbsp;&nbsp;05:04 pm</p>
</div>

<div class="newsContent"  style="width:100%; float:left; clear:both; margin-bottom:5px;"> 

<p>The police have seized ....</p>         
</div> 
</div>
<div class="clearFix"></div>

<!-- control:news headline item ends here --><!-- control:category list starts here -->
<!-- control:category list ends here -->
<!-- headline news article  -->
```

I want to get the full article corresponding to the description and get the image, 
can anyone help?

Comment: Don't use external links. Rather show a reasonable subset of the data you're working with right in the question.  NOTICE that RSS feeds contain sufficient data to resolve relative URLs like news_images/12345/blah.jpg in their headers. This data may be in the wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Good work, but it is not quite correct.

No images will show when you put the pipe output into a webpage because the links are **relative** to the original website and not yours. You could use the regex module to insert the rest of the missing URL and make the link **absolute** but the original website WILL be unhappy about you hotlinking to their images.

Yahoo pipes cannot get the images themsleves only the links to them. For your website to get a copy of those images is a bit more complicated and it would be better to do all the scraping from your websites server using PHP.

Something else to be aware of the **Fetch Page** Module will probably be gone in six months time or less, so you really need to start using the **XPATH Fetch Page** Module now.

Here's an incomplete pipe to get you started based upon your requirements.
http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.info?_id=d7aba8c124693f3af888838ca12ac547

**BTW** do not forget to swap in your own IDcodes for adverts and 'like' buttons or remove them completely with the regex module

Answer (score 0):

I've have fixed it by my self, here an screenshot of it.
it fetch the link and get the part I want and copy it to the description.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZ1lx.png]